# Django ORM - Filter by Multiple Columns Ranges

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-orm

I have a requirement to fetch the data (both `i_week` and `i_year`) for the last one year from current date. The table has the following columns. Let us call the table as `temp`.

- `i_week` - The week number [1,52]
- `i_year` - The year
- `Other columns`

I know how to fetch the data using SQL (Postgres). This is the query:

```
SELECT "i_week", "i_year" FROM "temp" WHERE ("i_week", "i_year") BETWEEN (1, 2021) AND (52, 2022);
```

What I have tried so far using Django ORM is this:

```
temp.objects.filter(i_week__range=(previous_week, current_week), i_year__range=(previous_year, current_year))
```

But this is not giving me the desired result.

How can I achieve the above SQL query using Django ORM ? How can I filter the ranges of `i_week` and `i_year` at once in ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

let's just mention the `Q` object method. You can try the ORM query this way:

```
from django.db.models import Q

temp.objects.filter(
Q(i_week__range=(previous_week, current_week)) & 
Q(i_year__range=(previous_year, current_year))
)
```

Comment: This is same as the ORM that I provided in the question.

Comment: No. Please have a look again we import a Q operator and with this we can add our condition like AND, OR with this Q operator in our query.                                                   Documentation link: https://micropyramid.com/blog/querying-with-django-q-objects/

Comment: I know about `Q` objects. I am not getting the desired output.

Comment: What is your desired output? Could you include it in your question? I just checked that (30, 2020) IS between (1, 2021) and (52, 2022), which might not be your desired output as well.